# How to connect user model with profile model in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, graphql, apollo

I am new to backend development And I am facing some issues with connecting `User` model with `Profile` model. And I also want to auto-generate `username` in profile model when user sets them in `User` model. I am not sure how to do this. Here is my code

> Resolver.js

```
Mutation: {
    signUpUser: async (parent, { userInput }) => {
      const { email, username, password } = userInput;
      const errors = [];
      if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
        errors.push({
          message: "Invalid Email",
        });
      }
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
      if (existingUser) {
        const error = new Error("User exists already");
        throw error;
      }
      if (errors.length > 0) {
        const error = new Error("Invalid Input");
        error.data = errors;
        error.code = 402;
        throw error;
      }
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);
      const user = new User({
        email: email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        username: username,
      });
      
      const createdUser = await user.save();
      
      return {
        ...createdUser._doc,
        _id: createdUser._id.toString(),
      };
    },
```

> UserModel

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      default: "I am new!",
    },
    posts: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Post",
      },
    ],
    profile: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Profile",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);


module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

> ProfileModel

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
    
      default: null,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
  
      default: null,
    },
    bio: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    profilePic: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    url: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Profile", profileSchema);
```

Here is the complete code if you like to give it a look

https://github.com/adityakmr7/medium-clone

Any help would be great. Thank you.
I am using Graphql here and apollo.

Comment: I need little help here. You'll create a profile doc first or a user doc?

Comment: with mongoose query, you can populate related stuff  
`Profile.findOne({ username: "test" }).populate('user')`

Comment: @n1th1l user first then profile

Comment: populate is from quering data what about saving data in profile model ?